# Catching server side ajax handling errors in browser

Tags: ajax, error-handling, wicket

Let's say I have some ajax based component, whose handler in server throws for some reason an exception (e.g. programming error, can't access database). And basically server responds with internal server error or some such. How can I catch this situation in browser and display for examplen an error message somewhere.

When user clicks this link, the server will show an error page and the browser should detect based on http status code that something went wrong and somehow to react to it.

```
new AjaxLink<Link>("link") {
   public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
      throw new RuntimeException();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See [org.apache.wicket.settings.IExceptionSettings#getAjaxErrorHandlingStrategy](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/settings/IExceptionSettings.html#getAjaxErrorHandlingStrategy%28%29).
There is an example of this at http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/links (failure and exception links).

Comment: That seems to be Wicket 1.5 only. Is there any way to do this in 1.4?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, Wicket Ajax classes like AjaxFallbackLink for example, have a method

```
updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes)
```

where you can register error handlers, that execute javascript within the browser.
 Override this method, create an AjaxCallListener and call

```
AjaxCallListener listener = new AjaxCallListener();
listener.onFailure(ADD_JAVASCRIPT_TO_EXECUTE_HERE);
attributes.getAjaxCallListeners().add(listener);
```

see the documentation of

org.apache.wicket.ajax.attributes.AjaxCallListener.getFailureHandler(Component component)